# Using a docker image on Wercker

Tags: docker, dockerhub, wercker

I am trying to use Wercker to eventually convert libreoffice files to pdf stored in a private Github repo. There are some Docker images on Dockerhub that contain libreoffice such as [xcgd/libreoffice](https://hub.docker.com/r/xcgd/libreoffice/) which has this [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/xcgd/libreoffice/~/dockerfile/).

I am new to both Docker and Wercker, so I decided to set up a minimal Wercker.yml to start from (below):

```
box: xcgd/libreoffice:latest
build:
    steps:
    - script:
        name: test python
        code: echo 123
deploy:
    steps:
    - script:
        name: my deploy script
        code: echo 123
```

The Wercker build stalls at the "setup environment" step with the last line being

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for xcgd/libreoffice:latest
```

And the build eventually times out with

"Command timed out after no response" after 12min 49s.

What am I doing wrong here?

Grateful for answers!

Comment: There seems to be another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786805/wercker-setup-environment-takes-too-long-and-make-the-build-fail) reporting an issue showing similar symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wercker.yml` looks like a good start, except that Docker is tricky, and using it on Wercker requires specific "incantations" :-)

It looks like the Docker container you've chosen defines [this `startoo.sh` script](https://bitbucket.org/xcgd/libreoffice/src/24f7d1c343df34cd9154194687d77739c3df142b/startoo.sh?fileviewer=file-view-default) as an `ENTRYPOINT`, which is basically the starting command when the container is loaded, see [Dockerfile docs for details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Trouble is, Wercker needs an `ENTRYPOINT` which can run a shell, as shown [here in the Wercker docs](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/containers/entrypoint.html).

As specified at the bottom of that [Wercker docs page](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/containers/entrypoint.html), the good news is you can override the `ENTRYPOINT` in your `wercker.yml` script.

Try changing the top of your `wercker.yml` to something like:

```
box: 
  id: xcgd/libreoffice:latest
  entrypoint: /bin/bash -c

build:
  ...
```

That should work to run your current Wercker `script` test steps, but now of course the `libreoffice` executable won't be running on the container, so later on you'll have to start it by running that script  `/opt/libreoffice/startoo.sh` yourself.